# DSolve couldnot give correct solution or full simplify couldnot simplify correctly

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I am using Mathematica 12.1.1 and solved the second order differential equation:

```
DSolve[y''[x] - 3 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 2 x^2 + 2 x*e^x, y[x], x]
```

... and it gave a lot of terms which needed simplifying so I used:

```
FullSimplify[%, x ∈ Reals]
```

... and it give all of the correct terms except one:

```
(2 e^x (3 + 2 x + Log[e] (-2 - 3 x + x Log[e])))/(2 - 3 Log[e] + Log[e]^2)^2
```

... which has a denominator of zero so I used the Wolfram Alpha website and it gave a correct simplified solution directly. Is there a bug in Mathematica?

Comment: The denominator is not zero. `Log[e]` is not 1. `e` is just a variable - Perhaps you meant to use `E` instead of `e` in your original equation to mean the Euler number? `DSolve[y''[x] - 3 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 2 x^2 + 2 x*E^x, y[x], x]` gives: `{{y[x] -> 
   1/2 (7 - 4 E^x + 6 x - 4 E^x x + 2 x^2 - 2 E^x x^2) + E^x C[1] + 
    E^(2 x) C[2]}}`

Comment: ok thankyou got it